# Merging git branches to master using Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, git-merge

I want to create a modular process which will merge the "devel" branch upon each successful build to the master branch, and it will also create a tag.
Is there any way to do it using Jenkins and Git plugin rather than writing code.
If yes, is there any option to provide Git plugin the repository URL as a parameter, so it will be as modular as possible.
The job that I want to create will be performing only the merge (`git merge --no-commit -X theirs`) operation and it will create a tag (the tag name will be provided as a parameter as well).This job will be triggered by other jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use post-build action Git Publish and provide to it's fields build parameters you have as a variables (for example $REPO_URL, if you have parameterized build with variable $REPO_URL or have Env Injection plugin with this variable).